# Wha is setting a cell to a value not working?

Tags: vba, set

This must be a very stupid problem, but I just cannot set a value into a cell. I have a very complex VBA file where I try to do that without success, so I simplified my test to a basic empty sheet that contains just one function:

```
Function test()
   Set Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.1415
End Function
```

a code copy/pasted from an example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value

It doesn't work. Cell A1 stays blank.

Can anyone see the elephant I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Set` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) assigns an object reference to a variable – for example, a reference to a worksheet:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

`3.1415` is a primitive value, not an object reference, so you'd do the assignment without `Set`:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 3.1415
```

Comment: OK fair enough, but even dropping the Set, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a worksheet named "Sheet1"?

Comment: Also, in VBA a function returns a value. Try changing `Function` to `Sub`.

Comment: Yes. It's a new default workbook containing just a call to the function test() in cell F1. Test is supposed to set A1 to 3.1415 as in the example (see above link)

Comment: Try opening the Immediate pane (Ctrl+G), pasting the line of code from the article you've linked to and pressing Enter. Alternatively, put the line into a Sub instead of a Function as above, then press the "run" button in the VBA editor to invoke it.

Comment: OK that worked. Using a sub allowed me to set the cell value. Same if I set a return value for the function. That means that my problem was due to an incomplete (no return value) call of a function. Thank for your help.